# Vaadin resize grid height with sub-window

Tags: java, grid, resize, vaadin, window-resize

I have a grid in a sub-window. The grid is set to full size and it fills the sub-window when I open it. But when I change the height of the sub-window, the height of the grid doesn't change. Only the width changes. Is there a way to change the height as well?

Code:

```
public class Fenster extends Window {
    Grid grid;
    BeanItemContainer<Kontrakt> container;

    public Fenster() {
        super("Orderbuch"); // Set window caption
        center();
        setWidth("1000px");

        VerticalLayout content = new VerticalLayout();
        grid = new Grid();
        grid.setColumnReorderingAllowed(true);
        grid.setSizeFull();
        grid.setEditorEnabled(true);

        kontrakte = Arrays.asList(
                new Kontrakt2[]{
                        //some items
                });

        container = new BeanItemContainer<Kontrakt>(Kontrakt.class);
        container.addAll(kontrakte);

        grid.setContainerDataSource(container);

        content.addComponent(grid);
        content.setExpandRatio(grid, 1f);
        content.setMargin(true);
        setContent(content);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my mistake by myself. I needed to add `content.setSizeFull();` for my layout to solve the problem.